# How to make nav bar stretch the full width of my page

Tags: html, css

I want to make my navigation bar stretch the full width of my page, but it doesnt want to stretch everytime I use width 100% the navbar just break and lose its form. I'm not using any javascript and i think the problem is on the .horizontal-centering class CMIW

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhG3b/)

I'm using pure css nav bar

```
/* dropdown.css */
 ul.dropdown, ul.dropdown li, ul.dropdown ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
    float: left;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
}
ul.dropdown ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
    float: none;
}
ul.dropdown ul ul {
    top: 1px;
    left: 99%;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
/* default.css */
 ul.dropdown {
    font: normal 16px"Square", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    padding: 7px 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: normal;
}
ul.dropdown a:link, ul.dropdown a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #005CE6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.dropdown a:active {
    color: #fff;
}
ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 170px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity: .9;
    KhtmlOpacity: .9;
    opacity: .9;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000;
    filter: none;
}
ul.dropdown ul li.hover, ul.dropdown ul li:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul.dropdown ul a:link, ul.dropdown ul a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
ul.dropdown ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.dropdown ul a:active {
    color: #fff;
}
ul.dropdown *.dir {
    padding-right: 12px;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* default.advanced.css */
 ul.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 14px;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown li.dir {
    padding: 7px 20px 7px 14px;
}
ul.dropdown ul li.dir {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
ul.dropdown ul a {
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 14px;
    width: 151px;
}
ul.dropdown ul a:hover {
    background-color: #005CE6;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > a.dir {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    color: #005CE6;
}
ul.dropdown ul li:hover > a.dir {
    background-color: #76b900;
    color: #fff;
}
html { *overflow-x: hidden; }
body { padding: 0; }
body, html { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.wrapper { min-height: 100%; min-width: 950px;overflow: hidden; }
.container { padding: 50px; }

.horizontal-centering { position: relative; }
.horizontal-centering > * > * { float: left; width: auto; position: relative; left: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.horizontal-centering > * > * > * { float: left; position: relative; right: 50%; }
```

Comment: have you cleared your floated elements?

Comment: well the float: left on ul.dropdown when i erased it and put bgcolor nothing seems work but if i put overflow: hidden it work but i cant see my dropdown bar

Comment: _“everytime I use width 100% the navbar just break and lose its form”_ – and that’s supposed to mean what exactly? Btw., whenever I see something like this, `z-index: 597` – I’m pretty sure someone is rather _guessing_ than knowing what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using overflow hidden to clear the floats by using a clearfix helper class this made the second level appear.

```
/* helper class for clearing floats */
 .clearfix:after{
   display: block;
   visibility: hidden;
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
   content:".";
  }
  .clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
    }
  .clearfix{ 
    display: block;
  }
```

Reworked the dropdown and centering a little

```
.horizontal-centering {
    background: #000000;
    position: relative;
}
.horizontal-centering > div > div {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-horizontal {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown > li > ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: 0;
}
ul.dropdown > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
ul.dropdown, ul.dropdown li, ul.dropdown ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown {
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover {
    cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
    float: none;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/35JPL/26/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/35JPL/26/show/

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works, but the dropdown is hidden because of overflow: hidden

Comment: Indeed, for multi-level menus would not work. I am trying something out which involves a slight other approach. Keep you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already found the trick http://jsfiddle.net/u67qx/6/ by some random dude

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle based on yours: http://jsfiddle.net/u67qx/

I added `width:100%` to some classes and I deleted left:50%; and right:50%;. Looks like this is what you want. You can align text to center.

Comment: If you've found the answer, please mark the answer and close the question =)

Comment: i want to make the text centered

Comment: text-align doesnt work it only align the text in the dropdown